# Should I not use a ternary expression if it pushes the line over 80 characters?

Tags: ruby

semantic question here. I like using ternary expressions; for example (and this is a dumb example just to illustrate my question):

```
    some_int >= 5 ? @description = "This is a pretty long value" : @description = "This value is a little shorter"
```

...but the line often gets pretty long. Should I use this instead:

```
    if some_int >= 5
      @description = "This is a pretty long value"
    else
      @description = "This value is a little shorter"
    end
```

Just to keep the individual lines shorter? Does shorter necessarily == more readable? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to keep lines under 80 characters?

Comment: @spickermann Because 80 characters is a safe assumption for minimum editor window width, go longer than that and it will line wrap or disappear off the right margin making it harder to read. Personally I assume 100 now that we have widescreens, but you need a minimum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
some_int >= 5 ? @description = "This is a pretty long value" : @description = "This value is a little shorter"
```

This is an improper use of a ternary. A ternary's sole use is when you're going to use the return value. It should be written like so (formatting issues aside):

```
@description = some_int >= 5 ? "This is a pretty long value" : "This value is a little shorter"
```

> *Should I not use a ternary expression if it pushes the line over 80 characters?*

Line length is the wrong metric. It's like asking if subroutines shouldn't be more than 25 lines (or whatever). It's not quite getting at the root of the problem and can lead to some awkward choices. The real question is complexity.

From a complexity POV your ternary is fine. It's a simple condition, simple statements, and it's using the return value. The problem is the statements are too long and they'll wrap. You can reformat them, as [@U-D13 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37950174/14660).

```
@description = some_int >= 5
    ? "This is a pretty long value"
    : "This value is a little shorter"
```

You could also put the strings into their own variables adding further clarification to the code.

```
@long_description  = "This is a pretty long value"
@short_description = "This value is a little shorter (except it's not)"

@description = some_int >= 5 ? @long_description : @short_description
```

Both tools are valid, and they can be combined. It's situational.

And hey, look at that, now the text is a configurable object variable.

Answer (score 2):

Break the expression into several lines:

```
@description = some_int >= 5
    ? "This is a pretty long value"
    : "This value is a little shorter"
```

This way you can keep the code readable and still have the ternary.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting thing about Ruby is you can use an `if` where a ternary would be too confusing or awkward:

```
@description =
  if some_int >= 5
    "This is a pretty long value"
  else
    "This value is a little shorter"
  end
```

This is considerably  easier to read at a glance than the ternary equivalent.

Both `if` and `case` work this way, returning the value that was triggered.

In general practice a ternary works best when you're dealing with very short values:

```
method_call(value > 5 ? :high : :low)
```

Beyond that it gets rather difficult to follow which can lead to unexpected bugs.